# Bluetooth vs BT Beacon

Tags: microcontroller, communication, bluetooth, digital-communications, bluetooth-low-energy

While trying to understand how BT devices work I came across another related term "BT Beacon". Is it same as BT communication or if a device is termed as BT beacon then it would have some specific feature added or reduced in it from the vanilla BT devices?

Edit:

Some references about BT and Beacons:

1. [BT Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_Low_Energy)
2. [Beacon Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_low_energy_beacon)
3. [BLE Made Simple](https://blog.beaconstac.com/2018/08/ble-made-simple-a-complete-guide-to-ble-bluetooth-beacons/)

Comment: where did you come across that term? Context helps! Might be just some Bluetooth LE advertisement, might be something else.

Comment: As explained at your previous question on this topic, bluetooth isn't really a great fit for your needs.  It's going to be a challenge to find a solution that fits your form factor that does not require mounting chip-scale packages yourself.  You were also already pointed to something that comes within a millimeter of meeting your goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BLE beacons only send advertising messages, however they can not be paired to.  An advertising message can contain a small amount of data.  So, a beacon broadcasts this data for any receiver.  (For example, a beacon may be broadcasting its own location in the advertising message.  If I receive that advertising message, then I know that I'm near that location.)

BLE beacons have the identical communications hardware and software stack, compared to other BLE devices.  They are configured to only send advertisement packages.

Comment: Let us say I have 2 Arduino boards which are communicating with each other over UART port. Now if I want to replace the UART Rx, Tx wires with BT modules then what should I use BT, BLE or Beacons?

Comment: BT, BLE or Beacons it looks like all 3 can be used.. only price difference.

Comment: Do yourself a service: find some Bluetooth documentation with some depth, and read it.